# grails datePicker submit date with timeZone

Tags: grails, datepicker, grails-controller

I am sending date through g:datePicker as Eastern time by default. 
How do I have an option where i pass date based on the timeZone selected?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Grails datepicker tag does not and should not deal with your timezone. Its just a presentation of date and accepts Date object. Meaning that whatever timezone the date object has it will be that.

There are number of libraries to handle timezone on client side such as [ECMAScript Internationalization API](http://norbertlindenberg.com/2012/12/ecmascript-internationalization-api/), [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and many others. On the server side you have libraries such as [Joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html) and so on. I am sure if you search on Google you can find plenty more options.

Just handle your timezone conversion, then the presentation layer could be Grails datepicker or bootstrap-datepicker or jquery and etc.